# Set default program for extension after msi installation

Tags: windows-installer, registry, installation, associations

Is there proper and working way to make extensions .mp3 default program with .msi installation? (I am using Advanced Installer).

So far I have tried:

Changing registry in Advanced installer for HKCU, HKLM, HKCR keys however it seems not to be working.

For example - I change those key values to my application but once I open mp3 file, registry automatically restores back to default. Why?

I had WMP11 as default, then I change it even manually with hand to my application, but then when i run my file, I press refresh on registry and it is WMP11 again.

I have tried using Advanced Installer built in solution - file associations. I filled up all required details and set it as my default program. But nothing works.

When I enter settings in Windows, I can see my application but it is inactive as default. I have to press and select it as default. But I need this to be done automatically since i will run my msi file with command line msiexec /i "myapp.msi" /qb and I dont need any user interaction..

Please help with ideas and let me know what is the proper way to do this.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Are you on Windows 10? Some [important changes](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2015/05/20/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-10122-for-pcs/#W2WGB1PBJFuFcxgU.99) have been included in it, as you can read in the linked article.

Here is an extras from the article:

> We know your defaults matter to you. With Windows 10, all apps – both Classic Windows apps and Universal Windows apps – will be unable to invoke a prompt to change your defaults, only Windows. You remain in full control of your default experiences, while reducing some of the unwanted noise that multiple prompts can bring.

Comment: I see.. there also was some workaround, like adding value - NoOpenWith to windows default app keys.
Seems not to be working anymore.
Any ideas what other work-arounds there could be?

Thanks

Comment: If I understand well, we cannot anymore modify key registry to set the default application ?
@user2396348, did you find any way to do it ?